# Onmouseover play different audio files for different image maps

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to make something that when you scroll over a certain part of the image, a different song plays with the onmouseenter and onmouseleave functions. It worked for the first image map, but for some reason it doesn't work with the second image map though it's pretty much the same. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="Uclashoes.jpeg" alt="EmptyShoes" width="1423" height="818" usemap="#shoesmap">
    </body>
    <a onmouseenter="document.getElementById('audioIDNerine').play()"
    onmouseleave="document.getElementById('audioIDNerine').pause()">
        <map name="shoesmap">
            <area shape ="rect" coords="980,400,1070,450"/>
        </map>
    </a>
    <audio id="audioIDNerine">
        <source src="Nerine.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    <a onmouseenter="document.getElementById('audioIDAriya').play()" onmouseleave="document.getElementById('audioIDAriya').pause()">
        <map name="shoesmap">
            <area shape ="rect" coords="1170,644,1293,790"/>
        </map>
    </a>
    <audio id="audioIDAriya">
        <source src="Ariya.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</html>
```

Comment: did you tried with changing the name of the map tag?

Answer (score 1):

welcome

You need study more hehe, you have several issues there. First, your HTML structure is wrong, second you have the same map repeated, I know differents values but need be only one. third, you have an A tag on the map. well I don't want bother you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg" alt="EmptyShoes" width="1423" height="818" usemap="#shoesmap">
        <map name="shoesmap">
            <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,200,450" onmouseover="document.getElementById('audioIDNerine').play()" onmouseout="document.getElementById('audioIDNerine').pause()"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="300,500,500,950" onmouseover="document.getElementById('audioIDAriya').play()" onmouseout="document.getElementById('audioIDAriya').pause()"/>
        </map>
        <audio id="audioIDNerine">
            <source src="https://www.zapsplat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/sound-effects-three/animals_alligator_hiss_002.mp3?_=1" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
        <audio id="audioIDAriya">
            <source src="https://www.zapsplat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/sound-effects-smartsound/smartsound_CARTOON_FX_Ricochet_Western.mp3?_=1" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/gL14pos2/) you have the fiddle with it, it has two map areas and two sounds, it may take some time while load but after load it works fine.